# El valor esperado debe ser estrictamente igual a: 1 y Recibo: -1

Tags: javascript

He intentado hacer lo siguiente pero no entiendo.

El valor esperado debe ser estrictamente igual a `1` y recibo `-1`.

Este es mi código:

```
var binarySearch = function (array, i) {
{
    var array = [];

    var mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2);  

    if (array[mid] === i) {
        return array[mid];
    } else if (array[mid] < i && array.length > 1) {
        return binarySearch(array.splice(mid, Number.MAX_VALUE), i);
    } else if (array[mid] > i && array.length > 1) {
        return binarySearch(array.splice(0, mid), i);
    } else {        
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**Ejemplo:**

> ```
> array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
> ```
>
> `binarySearch(array, 2)` **-->** Devolvería 1 ya que `array[1] = 2`
> (Donde 2 sería el número sobre el cuál queremos saber su posición en el array)

¿Cuál es el error?

¿Alguien me podría explicar? Por favor.

Comment: @padaleina Ejemplo:
//    array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
//    binarySearch(array, 2) --> Devolvería 1 ya que array[1] = 2
//    [Donde 2 sería el número sobre el cuál queremos saber su posición en el array]

Comment: @padaleina no se como editar el codigo soy nuevo x aca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunos problemas con tu código:

- No debes volver a definir el arreglo dentro de la función
- Al encontrar una coincidencia, devuelves el valor buscado y no el índice `return array[mid];`
- Se necesita agregar una variable extra a la función para identificar el índice real, porque en llamadas recursivas se reciben trozos del arreglo original, por ejemplo, al buscar `8`, en `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` en la llamada recursiva recibirás `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` y el índice original se pierde
- Finalmente, deberías usar [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) al obtener cada nuevo segmento para no modificar el arreglo original

Cambié los nombres de las variables internas para que tengan un poco más de sentido y te den la idea de lo que realmente se está haciendo.

```js
// Se van a recibir partes del arreglo, es necesario mantener un índice
let binarySearch = (haystack, needle, index = 0) => {
    // Evitar analizar si el arreglo no tiene elementos
    if(haystack.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    let mid = Math.floor(haystack.length / 2);
    if(haystack[mid] == needle) {
        // Hay coincidencia, se debe devolver índice "real", no valor
        return mid + index;
    } else if(haystack[mid] < needle && haystack.length > 1) {
        // Se incrementa el índice, porque se está enviando la parte "superior" del arreglo
        return binarySearch(haystack.slice(mid, Number.MAX_VALUE), needle, index + mid);
    } else if(haystack[mid] > needle && haystack.length > 1) {
        // El índice se mantiene porque se envía la parte "inferior" del arreglo
        return binarySearch(haystack.slice(0, mid), needle, index);
    }
    return -1;
};

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(binarySearch(arr, 2)); // 1
console.log(binarySearch(arr, 4)); // 3
console.log(binarySearch(arr, 8)); // 7
console.log(binarySearch(arr, 12)); // -1
```

Comment: gracias efectivamente ahi funciono !!! abrzo grande @Triby

Comment: @Pabmena, si se resolvió el problema, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así otros usuarios con problemas similares sabrán que esto puede servirles.

Answer (score 2):

Es correcto que te dé **`-1`**. Fíjate que tienes array definida 2 veces y el *scope* de ambas variables array es distinto. Mas allá de eso, luego de la segunda llave defines una variable array le asignas un array vacío. Luego le asignas a *mid* el valor de ese calculo que te da `0` porque la longitud de array es `0` y `0` dividido cualquier número es `0`. Y luego vienen los *ifs*.

Preguntas, si `array[0]` es igual al valor que tiene *i*...cualquiera sea el valor de *i*, eso es falso porque `array[0]` es nulo... y así todos los ifs hasta que cae en el `return -1`.

No sé la lógica de tu método pero pruébalo así:

```
var binarySearch = function (array, i) {
    var mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    if (array[mid] === i) {
      return array[mid];

    } else if (array[mid] < i && array.length > 1) {
      return binarySearch(array.splice(mid, Number.MAX_VALUE), i);

    } else if (array[mid] > i && array.length > 1) {
      return binarySearch(array.splice(0, mid), i);
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: × Debe devolver 1 para el arreglo [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] si busca el 2 (4 ms)
    × Debería devolver 4 para el arreglo [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] si busca el 5 (3 ms)
    √ Debería devolver -1 si no encuentra el valor buscado en el arreglo (3 ms)

Comment: me falla en los 2 primeros test. igual como el codigo q subi primero. debe ser un error minimo que me cambia los numeros,, me no me doy cuenta cual es

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que estás declarando una nueva variable array vacía al inicio de tu función, entonces tú array siempre está vacío.

```
var array = [];
```

Mi consejo es que intentes utilizar nombres más específicos, algo como: orderedArray. Como es una búsqueda binaria tiene como pre-condición un conjunto ordenado.

Saludos.